# time difference between timestamps in a pandas dataframe as histogram

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a data frame with one column that is all timestamps like below. What I need to do is now calculate the difference between each of the timestamps and then use those differences to plot as a histogram.
I am unable to decipher how to do the calculation on the differences. Any help would be appreciated.

```
0       2020-09-16 00:00:02.713264
1       2020-09-16 00:00:02.827854
2       2020-09-16 00:00:05.919288
3       2020-09-16 00:00:05.940775
4       2020-09-16 00:00:06.682184
```

[image]

Comment: you should be able to plot the difference in seconds as a histogram like `df['timestamp'].diff().dropna().dt.total_seconds().plot.hist()`

Comment: thank you. first half works great. but I'm getting an error on the plot - UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'less' input 1 from dtype('float64') to dtype('<m8[ns]') with casting rule 'same_kind'

the first value of the differences show  "NaT" - now sure if that is the cause.

Comment: added a `.dropna()` to my original comment; should work now.

Comment: thanks.the dropna work to remove the NaT but it wont plot. I'm getting this: UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'less' input 1 from dtype('float64') to dtype('<m8[ns]') with casting rule 'same_kind'
plus an empty plot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Diff on pandas dataframe with more than one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939896/diff-on-pandas-dataframe-with-more-than-one-column)

Answer (score 2):

given a dummy df

```
# df
#                    timestamp
# 0 2020-09-16 00:00:02.713264
# 1 2020-09-16 00:00:02.827854
# 2 2020-09-16 00:00:05.919288
# 3 2020-09-16 00:00:05.940775
# 4 2020-09-16 00:00:06.682184
```

you should be able to use

```
ax = df['timestamp'].diff().dropna().dt.total_seconds().plot.hist()
ax.set_xlabel('timedelta[s]')
```

...which should spawn a plot like
[image]