# Obtaining a list of items in a pandas column of timestamps where the time difference from one row to next is zero

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with a column that are timestamps of individual trades that occurred at BitMEX. I am now trying to work out the difference in times between each timestamp to the next using

```
timediff = df6['timestamp'].diff()
```

Then when I try `df6.timediff.isnull().sum()` I get the value as "one" which is the `NaT` value on top of the column for the first value.

However then when I draw a histogram I see many zeros. On inspecting the dataframe I see many rows with zero total.

Below are the timestamps I can see after doing the `.diff()`. I also see the timestamp no longer displays milliseconds either.

```
7463    0 days 00:00:00.342889

7464    0 days 00:01:07.891225

7465           0 days 00:00:00

7466    0 days 00:00:00.038494

7467    0 days 00:00:00.135066

7468           0 days 00:00:00

7469           0 days 00:00:00

7470           0 days 00:00:00

7471           0 days 00:00:00

7472    0 days 00:00:01.122758

7473    0 days 00:00:00.728908

7474    0 days 00:00:13.272938
```

My question is - how do I find the number of rows of timestamps that are actually zero - i.e. in this case the above timestamp is difference in time `(t - t(t-1))`

Comment: Just checking here, but did you make the datetime field an index? And I suppose you are trying to distinguish between actual 00:00:00.0000 and a missing timestamp of 00:00:00 ?

Comment: Please post the dtypes. Can it be that the column is string?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64063517/10197418 ?

Comment: haven't made it an index. I'm unsure why  I'm even getting 00:00:00. I simply did a .diff() to get the timestamp difference and ended up with some that are like this. somehow its also no taken as a null value either

Comment: when I check for type using type(xxx) I get this - pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta

Comment: [pd.isnull](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html) checks for missing values, not `== 0`, could that be the problem?

Comment: oh thank you that is true. I"ve done a zero count instead using .isin([0]).sum() and gave me the number of zeros. Thanks heaps.